# how to change camera object viewing

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

I've tried looking for the button or anything, but it is impossible. I'm new to blender, so please when you say the answer explain it in an easy-to-follow way. Problem: I have an object that I want to view from different angles, when I press middle mouse to move the camera it will rotate the camera around and not rotate around the object I clicked on. How do I switch/fix this? I DO NOT WANT TO CREATE AN ANIMATION. All the videos or help forums I try to look up online is for creating an orbiting animation, but I don't want that. Here is a picture to explain what I mean. Currently, when I press middle mouse to move the camera it will rotate around itself, showed by the gray arrows. What I want is to get the camera to rotate around the object shown by the green arrows. It is probably some simple button to press to switch these modes, but this is so annoying that it is so difficult for a new user to figure out on their own. [image]

Comment: In the Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan, have you enabled Orbit Around Selection, and in the 3D View > N panel > View > View Lock, have you enabled Camera to View?

Comment: It's actually not rotating around itself but around a point in the forward direction that is kind of randomly chosen when you middle mouse click. Blender doesn't support the behaviour you describe in your post unless you've set the active camera as viewport, locked it and start rotating around its local axis

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "camera will rotate around itself", but I'm guessing it's that you want to stay inside the camera view, but still control the rotation of the scene. For that, you can enable the *Lock: Camera to View* option under the <kbd>N</kbd> *> View > View Lock* panel.

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3cZVU2T
this is what i mean, the view is moving around itself not the object i clicked on. i want it to move around the object not around itself. How can i fix this? This only happened today, yesterday when i selected something the camera i guess "orbited" around it, now just spins on itself.

Comment: @confused new user, Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan, enable Orbit Around Selection, select the object you want, the camera will rotate around

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! it works now

Answer (score 3):

To complete Kuboa's answer, after having enabled *3D View > N panel > View > View Lock > Camera to View*, go into *Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan* and enable *Orbit Around Selection*. Now select the object you want, the camera will rotate around.

Comment: What I don't understand is, in the gif they've linked it looks like they're not even in the camera view, and it's behaving like the "Walk" navigation, not the usual orbiting. I never enable "Orbit Around Selection", that just makes the selected object the pivot point. I don't know how to replicate the behaviour in the gif honestly.

Comment: it looks like in your gif it's just Camera to View without orbiting around the selection, but the user is asking about how to rotate around the selection

Comment: No that's not what I mean. Forget about the camera, they're not even in the camera view in their gif, no? Their viewport camera is standing still and orbiting only makes it look around, just like in the "Walk/Fly" mode. I don't think they were asking to literally orbit around the selection, just the normal orbiting behaviour you see in my gif when I go out of Camera view. Maybe it's related to auto-depth https://youtu.be/G5JxQ0SPSfg?t=382 ? Maybe I'm having a brain freeze I don't know.

Comment: oh ok I understand what you mean, yes it's not even orbiting around the 3D cursor (which is the alternative to orbiting around selected if I'm right?), it's view (not even camera) rotating around itself... I don't know why

Comment: Actually when you're close to the 3D cursor it acts as if the camera was rotating around itself, no?

Comment: I don't think it ever rotates around the 3D Cursor, if "Orbit Around Selection" is not selected, it rotates around "the point of interest", as the manual calls it, basically the 3D point you clicked on with the middle mouse button. Auto Depth makes it so that when calculating that point of interest, it takes into account the geometry under your cursor at the moment you pressed the mmb. But no combination of those options will produce what the OP shows in their gif, only the "Walk" mode will, but that's a mode you enter with a shortcut, not a default so I have no idea how they got it.

Comment: @Kuboå my fault, i didnt mean camera. i dont know what all of these things are called. so i just thought camera was appropriate. i didnt know that black triangle was a camera. i was talking about how i was viewing the object this is what i wanted from the start and moonboots helped me. https://imgur.com/a/Cnb0iab <---- the second part of that clip is what i was trying to get.

Comment: @ Kuboå, I'm not sure what this "point of interest" is, I'm used to Orbit Around Selection, the default mode makes me sea sick actually  ^^

Comment: @confusednewuser Ah, this new gif's perspective makes it more clear, thanks. I think your "Auto depth" is off in Preferences. This is how I have mine set: https://i.imgur.com/XjGYnBe.png Glad you got is as you like now.

Comment: @moonboots "Point of interest" is just Blender guessing where in 3D space you're clicking on at that moment so you're mostly orbiting around what you're seeing, though it's not perfect by any means especially when it's an empty space your cursor is on. When "Auto Depth" is on, it looks at what objects you have under your cursor and assumes that's what you wanna orbit around, kinda like a semi-automatic "orbit around selection" but without having to select. I like it that way, but of course it's just preference :)

Comment: @Kuboå ok thanks for the precision, I'm glad with Orbit Around Selection though